# Upgrade Openstack production grade system from Pike to Victoria or some stable newer version

Tags: openstack

We are planning to upgrade our Openstack production environment from from Pike to Victoria version.

1. To upgrade what should be strategies?
2. What would be upgrade paths like Pike-> queens -> Rocky -> Stein -> train -> Ussuri -> Victoria
3. Is upgrade from Pike to Victoria version possible in one upgrade process.

We are using the open community version of Openstack version over Centos.
Please provide the inputs how should we proceed.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible to upgrade from Pika to Victoria, but it depends heavily upon your setup and your requirements. If you need to upgrade with zero downtime, or use a lot of custom options (e.g. 3rd party drivers, neutron-lbaas) it will be more difficult.

These are all too complicated to cover in a single Stackoverflow post and I would recommend that you hire a specialist, or ask on IRC or the official mailing lists for advice.

To address your individual points.

1. Depends heavily on your setup and requires a lot of research to determine the best strategy.
2. That is the recommended upgrade path. At the very least the database steps should be completed in that fashion.
3. Upgrading is for sure possible, but depends heavily on your environment and your requirements.

If your environment is small it might be worth to just build a new environment and manually migrate your workloads over.